# Matplotlib: Toolbar vs Toolmanager, ToolbarQt vs NavigationToolbar2QT?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to embed the "home" function (i.e., "reset original review") to a widget button combined with other operations. Below is an example code I have.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
from matplotlib.widgets import Button
from random import randrange

matplotlib.use('QtAgg')
plt.rcParams['toolbar'] = 'toolmanager' # switch this row to see the difference.

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, figsize=(4,6))
ax.imshow([[1, 2], [5, 6]])

def change_color(event):
    ax.imshow([[randrange(10), randrange(10)], [randrange(10), randrange(10)]])
    plt.get_current_fig_manager().toolbar.home()

axprev0 = plt.axes([0.35, 0.05, 0.3, 0.0375])
bprev0 = Button(axprev0, 'Change Color')
bprev0.on_clicked(change_color)

plt.show()
```

My problem is that when `plt.rcParams['toolbar'] = 'toolmanager'` is on, it shows error message `toolbar.home()` won't work. The reason I need  `plt.rcParams['toolbar'] = 'toolmanager'` is because it allows me to scroll the mouse wheel for zooming when I'm on the zoom or drag tool.

It seems that when we specify `plt.rcParams['toolbar'] = 'toolmanager'`, it is using `ToolbarQt`. The `ToolbarQt` supports mouse wheel scrolling for zooming. While the name of the home function of `ToolbarQt` is different.

If we do not specify `plt.rcParams['toolbar'] = 'toolmanager'`, plt is using  `NavigationToolbar2QT`. However, it does not support mouse wheel scrolling for zooming.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Can you post an image or add more information about what you mean by *'Home button'*?

Comment: Is the output figure getting generated in a new window or are you planning to do this inside a Jupyter Notebook or something?

Comment: @medium-dimensional I provided an example code to clarify my question. Could you take a look? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`plt.get_current_fig_manager().toolmanager.tools['home'].trigger(fig, event)` # use this function when toolmanager

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).